# Using virtual methods with Arduino

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, arduino, virtual-functions

I have a small piece of Arduino code that gives me compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'PushButton::PushButton(int, LeftButtonEvent*)
```

In its own header file I have two classes:

```
class Event
{
public:
    virtual void handle() {
    }
};

class PushButton
{
public:
    PushButton(int pinButton, Event *event);
    uint8_t read();
private:
    uint8_t _buttonState;
    Event _event;
};
```

And the source file for classes:

```
PushButton::PushButton(int pinButton, Event *event)
{
    // implementation
}

uint8_t PushButton::read() {
    // implementation

    return _buttonState;
}
```

In the main ino sketch header file I have defined a new class that extends Event class:

```
class LeftButtonEvent : public Event {
public:
    virtual void handle();
};
```

And in the sketch source file I provide the implementation for the handle method and use it:

```
void LeftButtonEvent::handle() {
    log("Is working!!!!!");
}

LeftButtonEvent leftButtonEvent;
PushButton leftButton;

void setup()   {    
    leftButton = PushButton(PIN_LEFT_BUTTON, &leftButtonEvent);
}
```

I was expecting the constructor for PushButton to accept a LeftButtonEvent type because it extends Event class, but it looks like it doesn't like it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What compiler are you using.  That ought to work.

Comment: Can you create a test like `struct Base{}; struct Derived: Base{} d; void f(Base *p){}; int main { f(&d); return 0; }` and see if that works? ... and then expand from there.

Comment: You are trying to create a `PushButton` object in the line `PushButton leftButton` without specifying arguments which requires a default constructor with no parameters. You don't have such a constructor on the `PushButton` class. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks MartinBonner & @Josef 
I'm using Arduino 1.0
I've moved the initialization from setup method and also tried to explicitly cast it to the base type like this:

    `PushButton leftButton = PushButton(PIN_LEFT_BUTTON, static_cast<Event *>(&leftButtonEvent));`

but still doesn't work ... gives 

    `error: invalid static_cast from type 'LeftButtonEvent*' to type 'Event*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is only incomplete code and I couldn't test it directly, there is example how it's possible to get it work (it's all in one sketch, Arduino IDE 1.6.12, C++11):

```
class Event {
  public:
    virtual void handle() = 0;
};

class EventLeft : public Event {
  public:
    virtual void handle() {
      Serial.println("EventLeft");
    }
} leftEvent;

class EventRight : public Event {
  public:
    virtual void handle() {
      Serial.println("EventRight");
    }
} rightEvent;

class PushButton {
  public:
    PushButton(int8_t _pin, Event * _event) : pin(_pin), state(true), event(_event) {
      pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    }

    void check() {
      if (! digitalRead(pin)) { // inverted logic
        if (state) event->handle();
        state = false;
      } else {
        state = true;
      }
    }

  private:
    int8_t    pin;
    bool    state;
    Event * event;
};

PushButton buttons[] = {
  {4, &leftEvent},
  {5, &rightEvent}
};

void setup()   {    
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);

  for (PushButton & button : buttons) button.check();
  //// if the range based for loop above doesn't work, you have to use old school one:
  // for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) buttons[i].check();
}
```

Comment: Except for the for-each construct, compiles fine with slightly older avr-gcc, too. (arduino 1.6.7 )

Comment: This is what I wanted to achieve. However I was having compilation problems even with your code and apparently the issue was generated by Visual Micro with Visual Studio Community 2015, I've switched to AmtelStudio 7 and everything seems to work.